# What species of bird is in this recording from Bethesda MD?

Tags: united-states, birds, bird-identification

Recorded in September 2015 in Bethesda, MD.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8sb5jjx3maeuk4o/Birdcall_Sept_Bethesda.m4a?dl=0

The recording was created at 1:00 PM on Sept 24th. I didn't see the bird, but I think it was in my Mulberry tree. The closest body of water would be the Potomac, but that's at least two miles from here.

Sorry I can't provide more hints. I don't know a lot about birds, I just found the song quite striking.

Comment: Now my bird calling skills are a bit rusty, but if I'm not mistaken, that is the call of an Airbus A380...

Comment: Adam - if you are also the 'David' who posted the identical question, please use the 'contact us' link at the foot of the page to request the 2 accounts be merged.

Comment: Rory, I am not David. But I also posted it on Uclue so I expect that one of their researchers posted it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is asdanrnr from Uclue, I posted on your topic but after 14 days it is expiring and I am afraid my answer came too late, so here is my take :

I went through this list of birds in Maryland:
http://davenation.com/birds/

Your bird may be a Rose-breasted Grosbeak, you can here its song here :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NixrHvecZ8c

You're welcome.